# Adding more enemies over time in a Space Invaders game in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I try to add more enemies over time, for example when your score is larger than 5, there should be 2 enemies and so on. But every time when i hit a score of 5 the game crashes with the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\PycharmProjects\SpaceInvaders\main.py", line 106, in <module>
    enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried several things, like adding the score detection part in a loop, but all i tried didnt work.
Here is the code of the Game

```
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
enemies = 1

for i in range(enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('alien.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(-32)
    enemyX_change.append(0.2)
    enemyY_change.append(100)

bulletImg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletY_change = 1
bullet_state = "ready"

score = 0


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 20))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerX_change = 0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state == "ready":
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX < -20:
        playerX = 820
    if playerX > 820:
        playerX = -20

    player(playerX, playerY)

    for i in range(enemies):
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]

        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 0.2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i] / 7
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -0.2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i] / 7

        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score += 1
            print(score)
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
            enemyY[i] = -32

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"
    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    if score > 5:
        enemies = 2
    if score > 15:
        enemies = 3
    if score > 25:
        enemies = 4
    if score > 55:
        enemies = 5

    pygame.display.update()
```

how do i add more enemies when I hit the correct score without the game crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, enemies are only actually added at the beginning, at

```
for i in range(enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('alien.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(-32)
    enemyX_change.append(0.2)
    enemyY_change.append(100)
```

When you increase the `enemies` variable, you do not add anything the `enemyX` etc. lists. This is why you get an out of range error, when you try to access enemy information that is not in the list.

What you should do is append a new enemy to your lists at the same time as when you increment the variable. Since you already have a nice block of code for creating an enemy, I think you should put it in a function. You could also put the increment of the `enemy` variable in this function.

```
def spawnEnemy():
    global enemies
    enemies+=1
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('alien.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(-32)
    enemyX_change.append(0.2)
    enemyY_change.append(100)
```

Then, you can use this both in your initial spawning and in your new spawns at higher scores.

```
for i in range(enemies):
    spawnEnemy()
```

And also:

```
if score > 5:
    spawnEnemy()
if score > 15:
    spawnEnemy()
if score > 25:
    spawnEnemy()
if score > 55:
    spawnEnemy()
```

However your current conditions for spawning an enemy are incorrect, as a new enemy will get spawned every frame as long as the score is greater than the number given. You should just use `==` instead of `>`, so it only makes it one time.

```
if score == 5:
    spawnEnemy()
if score == 15:
    spawnEnemy()
if score == 25:
    spawnEnemy()
if score == 55:
    spawnEnemy()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not increase the length of `enemyX` when you add new enemies. Then, in this bit of code, `i` exceeds the largest index of `enemyX`, resulting in an error:

```
for i in range(enemies):
    enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
```

To fix this, I would add a bit of code after `enemies = 2` that creates a new enemy by adding an item to `enemyX`, `enemyY`, `enemyX_change` and `enemyY_change`.